# When trying to concatenate a string in ostringstream, which string contents are modified and reconstructed, string get added at beginning

Tags: c++, ostringstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of ostringstream's string constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840531/what-is-the-purpose-of-ostringstreams-string-constructor)

I am facing below issue.
I have an ostringstream say testStr.
I first insert few characters inside it using <<

```
testStr << somechar;
```

Then I modified:

```
testStr.Str("some string")
```

so that now testStr is containing "Some String"

Now I want to add some characters(say " " and "TEST") at the end so that it can become "Some String TEST".

```
testStr << " " << "TEST";
```

But I am getting " TESTString".
Please let me know what can be done?

Adding sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "Hello";
  s.str("WorldIsBeautiful");
  s << " " << "ENDS";
  std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
```

}

Output is " ENDSIsBeautiful" where as I expected "WorldIsBeautiful ENDS".

Comment: Please just show the full code, from ostringstream instationation to the point where you retrieve the string from it; it seems like testStr is modified somewhere inbetween `testStr.Str("...")` and `testStr << ...`, and after the last statement you're showing.

Comment: I just tried it myself and I think I can reproduce the issue: http://codepad.org/tAgB1BEU - I didn't even know that ther is a `str` overload to *set* the string...

Comment: that is indeed odd behavior, I didn't know ostringstream cleared the string on the first call to operator<< after calling `str(string)` - but so far I have only used `str(string)` to clear an `ostringstream`! No idea why it's implemented that way, it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation I have read so far

Comment: @BoPersson, Good catch, I've not seen this behaviour yet, but I guess I was right minus the why. It's always a good time to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not overly sure, but it looks like it's still set to write at the beginning. To fix this, you can call [`s.seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)`(0, std::ios_base::end);` to set the output position indicator back to the end. I have a working sample [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/216f9412a36726bbc0afa9d2596c191d):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::ostringstream s;
  s.str( "Hello" );
  s.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
  s << "x" << "World";
  std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
HelloxWorld
```

Comment: @learningstack, Be sure to read through Bo's link. It's pretty informative in explaining the why (which I had no idea about).